# Yup validation type error on lazy options call

Tags: reactjs, typescript, yup, typescript-types

We've had this type error for a while now and I don't know how to fix it, I've tried a bunch of ways, and the quick fix doesn't fix it either. My yup validation schema for yup.lazy when I pass in item and options displays an type error in typescript, and I don't know how to fix it. How do I pass in a proper yup.StringSchema for this?

Here is my code:

```
export const schema = yup.object().shape({
  contactID: yup.string().required('Please select an option').nullable(),
  firstName: yup.string().when('contactID', {
    is: 'other',
    then: yup.string().required('First Name is required').nullable(),
    otherwise: yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  lastName: yup.string().when('contactID', {
    is: 'other',
    then: yup.string().required('Last Name is required').nullable(),
    otherwise: yup.string().nullable(),
  }),
  insuredName: yup.string().nullable(),
  phoneNumber: personaSchemaSwitch({
    is: (value: any) => makePersonaCheck(value, [CustomerTypes.SaAgent]),
    then: phoneValidation(true),
    otherwise: phoneValidation(true).required('Phone Number is required'),
  }),
  phoneNumbers: yup.array().of(
    yup.object().shape({
      phoneNumber: yup.lazy((item: any, options: any) => {
        if (options.path === 'insuredContactInformation.phoneNumbers[0].phoneNumber') {
          return phoneValidation(true).required('Phone Number is required');
        } else {
          return phoneValidation(true).nullable();
        }
      }),
      phoneType: yup.lazy((item: any, options: any) => {
        if (options.parent.phoneNumber !== '') {
          return yup.string().required('Phone Type is required');
        } else {
          return yup.string().nullable();
        }
      }),
    })
  ),
  phoneType: yup.string().nullable(),
  email: emailValidation(true).nullable(),
  relationshipToInsured: yup.string().nullable(),
});
```

Here's the error that's being displayed:
[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RO8RJ.png)